# How to preview custom html pages by using dugway server?

Tags: html, e-commerce, bigcartel

I’m designing a custom [Big Cartel](http://bigcartel.com/) theme by using [Dugway](https://github.com/bigcartel/dugway) for local development. I can access to and modify the barebones versions of the theme, e.g 127.0.0.1:9292/products which renders products.html from the source directory. Now if I want to preview a new custom page — let’s say resellers.html — 127.0.0.1:9292/resellers throws a Not Found error. How can I — or is it possible to — preview custom html pages by using dugway server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answered by ihearithurts from an [issue](https://github.com/bigcartel/dugway/issues/90) on github**

> Dugway takes all of its data from live Big Cartel stores, so to preview *a custom html* page you'd need to add it to a real store on bigcartel.com and then point your theme's config.ru [subdomain](https://github.com/bigcartel/dugway#store-content) to it.